# how do you send a SOAP request?

Tags: xml, http, soap

I am new to SOAP and xml. I read a number of tutorials but nothing seems to be clear enough.

I am abit confused, Just how does one send an SOAP request? The way I have tried to do this is by saving my SOAP request (as seen below) as: testRequest.xml.

```
POST /MobileCashPayout.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.80
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap12:Body>
<Payout xmlns="http://www.mycel.com/">
<Username>string</Username>
<Password>string</Password>
<referenceID>string</referenceID>
<sourceMsisdn>string</sourceMsisdn>
<destMsisdn>string</destMsisdn>
<Amount>decimal</Amount>
<MobilePin>string</MobilePin>
<cashInformation>string</cashInformation>
<merchantName>string</merchantName>
</Payout>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I then open the file (testRequest.xml) with a browser in order for it to be sent..

what I get in return is an error message stating:
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: localhost/projects/test.xml
Line Number 1, Column 1:POST /MobileCashPayout.asmx HTTP/1.1
^

Am I sending it the wrong way?
Please help me out?

Comment: The XML content starts with `<?xml`. Everything before that is HTTP headers. What platform are you using? Java?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Opening this document in browser wouldn't send a request. You have several options:

- write a little script in any familiar language, script should connect to specified server and send a POST request with a body as mentioned in your message
- use some of existing programs to do that for you

If you're inexperienced I would definitely recommend second option. My personal favourite is SoapUI, see [here](http://www.soapui.org).

Comment: Thank you, I am very familiar with PHP. I would need some guidelines though. Soap UI doesnt really help because SoapUI uses WSDL/WADL and not the required xml. Any guidelines?

Comment: You're right, SoapUI requires a definition of Web service that you wish to use. Web services are usually defined in .wsdl files (WSDL = Web Service Description Language), so all you need is a wsdl of MobileCashPayout service that you're calling. Most probably, it can be found if you type <URL>/MobileCashPayout.asmx?wsdl (where you replace <URL> with actual URL where the service is located). Please let me know if you succeeded.

Comment: I did try your solution but, get a

Comment: I tried your solution in a browser but I get a "404 Error: The page you are looking for could not be found!" SOAPUI I get: Error loading [http://URL-to-the-web-service/MobileCashPayout.asmx?wsdl]:Org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlExceptions:Org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlExceptions: error Unexpected character encountered lex state 8:';' Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you contact the provider of web service to let you know the location of the service and/or to send you the WSDL? When integrating with someone else's web service, it's common practice that provider of the service sends you the WSDL.

Comment: You can also use Postman. It has a great UI. I find it better than SoapUI (2019 ~ 7 years later). Link: https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: @WinningAddicted I find Postman great for communicating with REST APIs; however for SOAP-based APIs SoapUI is still my favourite.

Answer (score 7):

This blog post helped me. 
[Python SOAP Request using Requests](http://daycoder.blogspot.com/2013/03/python-soap-request-using-requests.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import requests
from XML import XML

request = u"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
                  <soapenv:header>
                  <soapenv:body>
                      <web:conversionrate>
                          <web:fromcurrency>GBP</web:fromcurrency>
                          <web:tocurrency>CHF</web:tocurrency>
                      </web:conversionrate>
                  </soapenv:body>
              </soapenv:header></soapenv:envelope>"""

encoded_request = request.encode('utf-8')

headers = {"Host": "www.webservicex.net",
           "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
           "Content-Length": len(encoded_request)}

response = requests.post(url="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx",
                         headers = headers,
                         data = encoded_request,
                         verify=False)

print unicode(XML(response.text))
```

Comment: FYI, it's link only answer, must include essential details/code from the link her because link may no longer exist in future!

Answer (score 4):

On linux you can use `curl` to send the soap xml. Here's how to do it:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction: ACTION_YOU_WANT_TO_CALL" --data @FILE_NAME URL_OF_THE_SOAP_WEB_SERVICE_ENDPOINT
```

Using the `testRequest.xml` file created you can

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction: ACTION_YOU_WANT_TO_CALL" --data @testRequest.xml URL_OF_THE_SOAP_WEB_SERVICE_ENDPOINT
```

Here is a [link](http://dasunhegoda.com/make-soap-request-command-line-curl/596/) that describes the full process.

Comment: I will always like curl. Simple.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send a soap request when a browser as far as I know. 
I propose you use a tool like [Soap UI](http://www.soapui.org/)

to send a request.

Comment: Thank you, your reply was insightful because you introduced me to Soap UI. The problem is that the initial SOAP code above is written in XML and not in WSDL/WADL. Soap UI uses WSDL/WADL and not the required XML.   Any ideas?

Comment: SOAP UI supports XML formated and editable requests and provides XML formated responses. You can copy & paste your XML into SOAP request window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use postman. It is good for REST and Soap
https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/supported-api-frameworks/making-soap-requests/

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell solution. Replace all items in angle brackets with correct value.

```
$svc = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://<server>/MobileCashPayout.asmx?op=Payout"
$x=$svc.Payout("<Username>","<Password>","<referenceID>","<sourceMsisdn>","<destMsisdn>",<Amount>,"<MobilePin>","<cashInformation>","<merchantName>")
```