# How can I send SOAP request via a HTTP request tool?

Tags: http, soap

I found this,
[how do you send a SOAP request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446822/how-do-you-send-a-soap-request)
But it was based on a certain programming language.

I want to do this via a HTTP request tool such as HttpRequester on firefox or postman on Chrome, or just this [online tool](https://reqbin.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use soapui. This is the best tool for SOAP to my knowledge,, it is free and open source too.

https://www.soapui.org/
Free version can be downloaded here: https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html